# FreeSWITCH dynamic IVR entry/bridge

Tags: php, freeswitch, ivr

Not sure what's the best approach to do this and not even sure if it's doable. I have PHP and MySQL, FreeSWITCH, FreeSWITCH PHP ESL setup on my server and a SIP phone number binded to the gateway. In the database I have a table storing pairs of phone numbers that I want to bridge calls between. A short version of the table looks like below:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+
|     |   Callee_1   |   Callee_2   |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
|  1  |  1112223333  |  2223334444  |
|  2  |  6667778888  |  7778889999  |
|  3  |  1123581321  |  3455891442  |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

What I've been trying to achieve is to build a automated call center with FreeSWITCH in a way that I can make an automated call to Callee_1 in the table and play an IVR once Callee_1 picks up. If Callee_1 presses 1 I will bridge the the call to Callee_2 so they can speak on the phone.

I was thinking about to setup a CronJob that fetches new rows from the table periodically then loop through them and use [PHP ESL](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/PHP_ESL) to originate calls to Callee_1. Something like

```
$sock->api("originate sofia/gateway/myProvider/$Callee_1 &ivr(my_ivr)");
```

my_ivr:

```
<menu name="my_ivr"
    greet-long="say:Thank you for filling out the form."
    greet-short="say:Thank you.
    ......
    digit-len="4">
  <entry action="menu-exec-app" digit="1" param="bridge sofia/gateway/myProvider/Callee_2/>
</menu>
```

Everything seems fine up till now yet I ran into the problem of how to pass the corresponding Callee_2's phone number to the IVR entry dynamically. Should I rewrite the ivr xml and do a reload for every pair? I tried configuring the [mod_xml_curl](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_xml_curl) yet no luck. The fs_cli generates "405 not allowed" error every time I try to reload IVR. I also checked out the HTTAPI seems it doesn't fit my need here as it requires using session.
Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the OP and now answering my own question. It turned out that I was over complicating the whole thing and FreeSWITCH is extremely intuitive to use. Simply setting a channel variable

```
originate {callee_2=2223334444}sofia/gateway/myProvider/1112223333 &ivr(my_ivr)
```

and accessing the channel variable in the ivr xml

```
<menu name="my_ivr"
    greet-long="say:Thank you for filling out the form."
    greet-short="say:Thank you.
    ......
    digit-len="4">
  <entry action="menu-exec-app" digit="1" param="bridge sofia/gateway/myProvider/${callee_2}/>
</menu>
```

will do the trick. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in `menu-exec-app`, you can execute a Lua or some other script which looks up the destination in the database.

Comment: Hi @Stanislav, thanks again for the help. Say I have the connection to the database, how should I select the corresponding Callee_2 that is associated with the current Callee_1. Is there any way that I can pass the uid as a channel variable to the IVR so I can associate them together.

Comment: there's a big number of channel variables which are available for the IVR and the called Lua script. I think you just need to learn the platform and read the FreeSWITCH book